# MS Sql Trigger send data to external MySQL server

Tags: sql-server

is it possible to make a MS SQL trigger that on change make the same change on external server MySQL database ?

Thank you in advice!

Comment: Yes, it is. Though I'd urge caution; if that trigger fails, so will your "change" on your SQL Server.

Comment: The [Recommended route these days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/heterogeneous-database-replication?view=sql-server-2017) would be to combine CDC and an SSIS package. As Larnu says, trying to do this from a trigger is a bad idea. Your database goes from being reliable in and of itself to only being as reliable as itself, the remote server, the network between them, etc.

Comment: Either way, Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. We can let you know it's possible, but the volunteers aren't here to do the work for you; that's your job (you get paid to do it after all!). If you start on the process and run into difficulty, then please do ask another question. Include what you've tried (the code), along with any specific error messages, and we'll be able to help you get past that **specific** problem. If you're looking for guides, I suggest [Google](http://google.com), [Bing](http://bing.com), or your preferred search engine. I've voted to close this as "too broad".

Comment: Hello All, thank you for your help!